# How to automatically input time & date in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help. I want Rows B & C to automatically fill in time and date respectively when I input data in D. I would also like for Row I to automatically add time when I input data into Row H.

I've tried ARRAYFORMULA IF with NOW and TODAY but time resets every time I input a value below the column, and date resets every time I open the sheet the next day. Any insight would be helpful!

Here is how my sheet looks like:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNTPr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in your script editor, change sheetName if any, save, and try within your sheet, set format of columns B, C and I as you wish

```
function onEdit(event){ 
  var sheetName = "mySheet";
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if ((r.getColumn() == 4) && (sh.getName() == sheetName)){ 
    sh.getRange('B'+r.getRow()).setValue(new Date());
    sh.getRange('C'+r.getRow()).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if ((r.getColumn() == 8) && (sh.getName() == sheetName)){ 
    sh.getRange('I'+r.getRow()).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

you may probably to execute once in your script editor to give authorization (even if you get an error)

Answer (score 0):

Description

You could use a simple onEdit(e) trigger. The script below is tested using Sheet1.

A minor twist on Mike's answer in that the number format is set too.

Script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    var now = new Date();
    var range = null;
    // make sure the edit occured on the right sheet
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1") {
      // make sure the edit occured in column D
      if( e.range.getColumn() === 4 ) {
        range = e.range.offset(0,-3);
        range.setValue(now);
        range.setNumberFormat("m/d/yyy");
        range = e.range.offset(0,-2);
        range.setValue(now);
        range.setNumberFormat("h:mm:ss am/pm");
      }
      // or make sure the edit occured in column I
      else if( e.range.getColumn() === 9 ) {
        range = e.range.offset(0,-1);
        range.setValue(now);
        range.setNumberFormat("h:mm:ss am/pm");
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use script, here is another solution:

1. Turn on "Interactive calculation" with "Max iterations"=1:

- File -> Settings -> Calculation:
- "Interactive calculation" = **On**
- "Max number of iterations" = **1**

2. Set format to column B = **Time**
3. Set format to column C = **Date**
4. Paste this formula to B2: `=IFS($D2="";"";B2="";NOW();TRUE;B2)`
5. Paste this formula to C2: `=IFS($D2="";"";C2="";NOW();TRUE;C2)`
6. Copy formulas in B2 and C2 down as long as you want.

Now, whenever you put anything in cells D2:D - the corresponding B- and C-cells will fill out a timestamp.

[image]

Comment: Mark: I use Norwegian formatting/settings. Change ";" with "," in formula for English formatting/settings.

Answer (score 0):

#### Adding Time and Date

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy"));
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"HH:mm:ss"));
  }
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}
```